# Conversion of XAML to PNG in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to perform XAML conversion (eg whole grid or viewbox) to png file?

I need to do this from the ViewModel level.

[Link to the example function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721353/6773519) that I can not call in ViewModel because I do not have access to the object.

Is there a simple and pleasant way?

Comment: Why does manipulation of view objects have to take place in the viewmodel? I would do the translation in the view and then pass the result to the viewmodel via a bound dependency property. Another bound dp could be used to initiate the process if it needs to be done from the viewmodel.

Comment: @Andy Can you say something more about transforming straight into xaml? Maybe an example?

Comment: You have code translates into a file. Google a bit more and you could find similar to translate to filestream so it's all in memory. Put that code in your code behind if it's only going to be used in one place or a re-usable class otherwise. You could even put it in a control ( with no ui ) and add dependency properties to that so you can bind the control you want to translate to one property and the result to a property in your viewmodel. Then maybe bind another dependency property so you can initiate the process from your viewmodel.

Comment: If that still makes no sense, come back and I'll write something later.

Comment: After a little more thought, probably best with just a dependency object rather than a control. You need a do of some sort so you can have dependency properties and bindings. This doesn't suit just one attached dependency property or a behaviour. IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The view will be responsible for actually exporting the elements that you see on the screen according to the answer you have linked to.

The view model should *initialize* the operation though. It can do so in a number of different ways.

One option is to send a loosely coupled event or message to the view using an event aggregator or a messenger. Please refer to the following blog post for more information on subject: http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/.

Another option is to inject the view model with a loose reference to the view. The view implements an interface and uses either constructor injection or property injection to inject itself into the view model, e.g.:

```
public interface IExport
{
    void Export(string filename);
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window, IExport
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel(this);
    }

    public void Export(string filename)
    {
        //export...
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly IExport _export;

    public ViewModel(IExport export)
    {
        _export = export;
    }

    public void DoExport()
    {
        //...
        _export.Export("pic.png");
    }
}
```

This way the view model only knows about and have a depdenceny upon an interface. It's has no dependency upon the view and in your unit tests you could easily provide a mock implementation of the `IExport` interface.

The view model will and should never have any access to the actual elements to be exported though. These belong to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [Interaction](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/interactions/) - a way for VM to take something from view. If you don't want to install a whole new framework for that, just use Func property:

Your VM:

```
public Func<string, Bitmap> GetBitmapOfElement {get;set;}
...

//in some command
 var bmp = GetBitmapOfElement("elementName");
```

Then, in your view you have assign something to that property:

```
ViewModel.GetBitmapOfElement = elementName =>
{
   var uiElement = FindElementByName(elementName); // this part you have figure out or just always use the same element

  return ExportToPng(FrameworkElement element); // this is the function form the link form your answer modified to return the bitmap instead of saving it to file
}
```

If you need it async, just change property type to `Func<string, Task<Bitmap>>` and assign async function in your view

Answer (score 0):

What about dependency properties? Consider the following class that is used to passing data (the data may be a stream or whatever you want):

```
public class Requester
{
    public event Action DataRequested;

    public object Data { get; set; }

    public void RequestData() => DataRequested?.Invoke();
}
```

Then you create a usercontrol and register a **dependency property** of type **Requester**:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RequesterProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("Requester", typeof(Requester), typeof(MainWindow),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(Requester), OnRequesterChanged));

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Requester Requester
    {
        get => (Requester) GetValue(RequesterProperty);
        set => SetValue(RequesterProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnRequesterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        => ((Requester) e.NewValue).DataRequested += ((MyUserControl) d).OnDataRequested;

    private void OnDataRequested()
    {
        Requester.Data = "XD";
    }
}
```

And your view model would look something like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public Requester Requester { get; } = new Requester();

    public void RequestData() => Requester.RequestData();
}
```

In XAML you simply bind the dependency property from your control to the property in your view model:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl Requester="{Binding Requester}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```